# How can I force a dask worker to not write data to disk?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to force a worker to not write data to disk, but probably I'm doing something wrong.

I have modified the file ~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml as follows:

```
distributed:
  worker:
    # Fractions of worker memory at which we take action to avoid memory blowup
    # Set any of the lower three values to False to turn off the behavior entirely
    memory:
      target: 1.00  # target fraction to stay below
      spill: 1.00  # fraction at which we spill to disk
      pause: 1.00  # fraction at which we pause worker threads
      terminate: 1.00  # fraction at which we terminate the worker
```

But they just keep writing to disk any temporary result. I have also tried to use a fictitious memory-limit setting (100GB), but still they write on disk at the end of a task. How can I force them to keep all in memory? 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing should work fine.  I'm surprised that it doesn't for you.

The official recommendation is to use `false` values, as is described here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html#no-local-storage

```
distributed:
  worker:
    memory:
      target: false  # don't spill to disk
      spill: false  # don't spill to disk
      pause: 0.80  # pause execution at 80% memory use
      terminate: 0.95  # restart the worker at 95% use
```